# проблема создания папки программным образом на iPhone

Tags: c#, unity3d

При получении проекта с сервера, приложению необходимо создать под этот проект папку с названием проекта. Если запускать приложение в Unity - всё будет работать нормально, а если это сделать на iPhone, то будет кидаться исключение.

Вот пример проекта, где я хочу создать папку fold. При попытке её создать я получил следующее исключение:

"Accessto the pass "var/containers/Bundle/Application/47C4748D-5E50-444A-BF43-75280B3FC3A0/CreateRepos.app/Data/Raw/fold"" is denied.

Папка создаётся следующим образом:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.dataPath + "/Raw/fold");
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её решить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взято из документации по Unity:

`Application.dataPath` для iOS возвращает такой путь:

`<path to player app bundle>/<AppName.app>/Data` и эта папка доступна только для чтения.

Для записи используйте этот путь:  `Application.persistentDataPath`

Ссылка на документацию: [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое )))

Comment: @AsifMamedov а плюсануть и принять ответ?